# How to Change border of selecteditem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one main window.xaml, inside which i have referred Viewmodel and another xaml page called Template.xaml.

Mainwindow.xaml will be some thing like below:

```
<Window ...>
<Window.Resorce ../>
<Window.DataContext>
<local:Viemodel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid...
<local:Template/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is my Tempaltes.Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ControlsList}" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Width="950"
                                       Margin="28"
                                       KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
                                       Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Name="Mybutton" Height="200" Background="Red" Command="{Binding Path=SupportButton}">
```

.....

In tha above block i have used binding in 3 places.
1. Item Controls
2. Button
3. Image
And here the command binding was not working for "MyButton". What may the reason behind this?

I need to change the background of button once the particular item is chosen. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Under the button properties there is additionally a tab for actions or action methods. You'll want to find the one that is a button clicked event.

Once you have created an event handler from that action you will have the ability to change the background or foreground of the button.

Comment: Why not command binding? I have list of controls, Background should be change when i choose the particular control.while using click event once the background get changed it remains, even though i move on to another control

Answer (score 0):

Not 10% sure what you're trying to achieve here, but perhaps a ListBox would work better for you?

It'll automatically change the background of the item while it's selected and remove the background when another item is selected. If you want to perform an action when the selected item changes you could bind to the SelectedItem property.

Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from the question but it sounds like using a ToggleButton may be appropriate in your case.  If you go that route, you could simply bind the IsChecked property to your View Model, and your property setter could perform any command-like logic.

And of course you could style the ToggleButton any way you like, so the IsChecked state could look relatively different from the Normal state.